# How to set value for date input with value is next date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a date input

```
<input id="myDate" type="date" />
```

How to set value for this input is the next date?

Comment: Must be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to get tomo's date and set for the input  after dom elements are loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
$("#myDate").val(date);
});
```